# HTML background opacity no to affect the foreground

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have an image for my background that has an opacity on .4.  I have an image in front of it that seems have the same opacity.  What do I do so the opacity of the front image is 1.0?

Here is a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/aaronmk2/6zjtgxdm/150/

Here is my html

```
<div>Hello World

<img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/11/11/article-2500617-007F32C500000258-970_306x423.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

and my css

```
div{
    width : auto;
    height : 1000px;
    background-image : url("http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/11/11/article-2500617-007F32C500000258-970_306x423.jpg");
    background-position:  65% 65%;
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  background-size:     cover;
  opacity: .4;
}
```

Comment: See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. You need to put your background image in the `div::after` pseudo element, like this :

```
div{
    width : auto;
    height : 1000px;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  background-image : url("http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/11/11/article-2500617-007F32C500000258-970_306x423.jpg");
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; 
  background-position:  65% 65%;
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  background-size:     cover;
}
```

Like this, the `div` element doesn't have the transparent opacity, which was previously applied to its child element, the image.

[I updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zjtgxdm/151/)

Answer (score 2):

you can give div position relative and use before with same image and give before same opacity.
you can check below given code within jsfiddle.

```
/* Here is the code Start */
div{
    width : auto;
    height : 1000px;
    position:relative;
}
div:before{
  content:" ";
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-image : url("http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/11/11/article-2500617-007F32C500000258-970_306x423.jpg");
  background-position:  65% 65%;
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  background-size:     cover;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
/* Here is the code Start */
```